# Azure Service bus exception - The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have been thru all of the other matching questions but cannot find an answer. The main thing that is different is; I have the same code running on my laptop as on my desktop, one works the other doesn't. My code was working fine on my desktop, then I made some major changes to my code and I started getting this exception. So I tried rolling back, still received the exception. Then I tried deleting the topic and recreating it, I still received the same exception. Then I tried deleting everything in my development directory and cloning the repo again, and loaded up the old code from when it was working, still I get the exception. Finally I worked on it at home on my laptop, and I did not have the exception. It works on my laptop but not on my Desktop. Any Ideas on what it could be?

I tried breaking down the code to a bare minimum. The receive looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static ITopicClient topicClient;
    static ISubscriptionClient subscriptionClient;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionStringServiceBus = "Endpoint=sb://XXX-eventbus2.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx";
        string topicName = "wb-org-events";
        string SubscriptionName = "ExamAdministration";

        subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(connectionStringServiceBus, topicName, SubscriptionName);

        Console.WriteLine("======================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit after receiving all the messages.");
        Console.WriteLine("======================================================");

        //topicClient = new TopicClient(connectionStringServiceBus, topicName);

        RegisterMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages();

        Console.ReadKey();
        subscriptionClient.CloseAsync();
       // topicClient.CloseAsync().Wait();
    }
    static void RegisterMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
    {
        // Configure the MessageHandler Options in terms of exception handling, number of concurrent messages to deliver etc.  
        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
            AutoComplete = false
        };

        // Register the function that will process messages  
        subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
       
    }

    static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Process the message  
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: Sequence Number:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} \t Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

        await subscriptionClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
    // Use this Handler to look at the exceptions received on the MessagePump  
    static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception:: {exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception}.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In addition today I started outputting the UTCNow and the message.SystemProperties.LockeduntilUtc time. It makes no sense to me that the LockedUntilUtc time is 17 seconds in the past.
I changed the lock duration from the default to the maximum and the Exception goes away. So the renewal does not happen and therefore no exception. This does not seem like a good work around.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I have been working thru this sample. https://github.com/Daniel-Krzyczkowski/MicrosoftAzure/tree/master/asp-net-core-microservices-with-azure-and-docker my code is basically the same but I have started introducing my own queue, my own  IntegratedEvents, my own configuration files etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the clock on my PC was out by probably 40 seconds. Once I got it synced then the exception disappeared.